# What does "2>&1" do in command line?

Tags: command-line, shell, redirection

I know that the `>` sign is used for output redirection in the command line, but I'm having trouble finding something that explains the use of `2>&1` in the command line.  For example:

```
curl http://www.google.com > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: [What does >& mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11255447/995714), [What's the difference of redirect an output using “>”, “&>”, “>&” and “2&>”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4749226/995714)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The `1` denotes standard output (stdout). The `2` denotes standard error (stderr).

So `2>&1` says to send standard error to where ever standard output is being redirected as well. Which since it's being sent to `/dev/null` is akin to ignoring any output at all.

Comment: Is there a reason that an ampersand appears before the 1, but not before the 2?  I thought the & was a reserved character for running a job in the background, but I guess that's only if the ampersand appears as a long character at the end of a command...?

Comment: Because `0` (stdin), `1` (stdout) and `2` (stderr) are actually file descriptors the shell requires an ampersand put in front of them for redirection. It duplicates the file descriptor in this case effectively merging the two streams of information together.

Comment: Think of it this way: if you just had "1" with no ampersand, the shell would create a file named "1" and redirect stderr output to it.

Comment: Okay, would this alone be valid then? `curl http://www.google.com 2>/dev/null` How does the command line know that the "2" here is intended to mean stderr and isn't actually the second parameter that I'm passing to the curl command?

Comment: @Matt Huggins: Yes. That would send all output from `stderr` straight to `/dev/null` instead. You can see it in practice by trying `curl`, `curl 1>/dev/null` and `curl 2>/dev/null` just to see the output change. Again the ampersand is only needed for the file descriptor being redirected to.

Comment: @MattHuggins What does the & in the end do here, after 1??

Comment: @infantDev: The & at the very end of the command in the question means the command runs in the background.

Comment: is  ```2>&1  > /dev/null``` the same as  ```> /dev/null 2>&1 ```? It seems more natural to me...

Comment: @edelans No, order matters, so `2>&1` will redirect stderr to the **current** value of stdout, then `>/dev/null` changes stdout. See [cmd-21-log-vs-cmd-log-21](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699790/cmd-21-log-vs-cmd-log-21)

Comment: @Nigel thanks, it's crystal clear now, +1 for linking to such a clean answer.

Answer (score 47):

### tl;dr

Fetch `http://www.google.com` in the [background](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_process#Launch_.26_resumption_on_Unix) and discard both the `stdout` and `stderr`.

> `curl http://www.google.com > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

is the same as

> `curl http://www.google.com > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &`

### Basics

`0`, `1` and `2` represent the standard file [descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) in [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) operating systems. A file descriptor is a system reference to (basically) a file or [socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket).

- [`0 stdin`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29)
- [`1 stdout`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)
- [`2 stderr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29)

Creating a new file descriptor in C can look something like this:

```c
fd = open("data.dat", O_RDONLY)
```

Most Unix system commands take some input and output the result to the terminal. [`curl`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL#Examples_of_cURL_use_from_command_line) will fetch whatever is at the specified url (*google dot com*) and display the result to `stdout`.

[image: curl result]

### Redirection

Like you said `<` and `>` are used to redirect the output from a command to somewhere else, like a file.

For example, in `ls > myfiles.txt`, [`ls`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls) gets the current directory's contents and `>` redirects its output to `myfiles.txt` (if the file doesn't exist it is created, otherwise overwritten, but you can use `>>` instead of `>` to append to the file instead). If you run the command above, you will notice nothing is displayed to the terminal. That usually means success in Unix systems. To check this `cat myfiles.txt` to display the file contents to the screen.

### > /dev/null 2>&1

The first part `> /dev/null` redirects the `stdout`, that is `curl`'s output to `/dev/null` (more on this ahead) and `2>&1` redirects the `stderr` to the `stdout` (which was just redirected to `/dev/null` so everything will be sent to `/dev/null`).

The left side of `2>&1` tells you **what** will be redirected, and the right side tells you **where** to. The `&` is used on the right side to distinguish `stdout (1)` or `stderr (2)` from files named `1` or `2`. So, `2>1` would end up creating a new file (if it doesn't exist already) named `1` and dump the `stderr` result in there.

### [/dev/null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device)

`/dev/null` is an empty file, a mechanism used to discard everything written to it. So,
`curl http://www.google.com > /dev/null` is effectively suppressing `curl`'s output.

[image: > /dev/null]

But **why** is there some stuff still displayed on the terminal?. This is **not** `curl`'s regular output, but data sent to the `stderr`, used here for displaying progress and diagnostic information and not just *errors*.

`curl http://www.google.com > /dev/null 2>&1` ignores both `curl`'s output and `curl`s progress information. The result is nothing is displayed on the terminal.

### Finally

The `&` at the end is how you tell the shell to run the command as a [job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_stream) in the [background](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_process#Launch_.26_resumption_on_Unix). This causes the [prompt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt) to return immediately while the command is run asynchronously behind the scenes. To see the current jobs type `jobs` in your terminal. Note this is [different](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/what-is-the-difference-between-a-job-and-a-process) from the processes running in your system. To see those type `top` in the terminal.

### References

- [When to use STDERR instead of STDOUT](http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7766119-when-to-use-stderr-instead-of-stdout)
- [Unix - Shell Input/Output Redirections](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-io-redirections.htm)
- [Standard Input and Output Redirection](http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/redirection.html)

Comment: This is one of the best answers on the entire website from a layout perspective, well done!

Comment: One thing I'm not getting is why you would want to send everything to `/dev/null` ? Don't you want the results of the `curl` at least somewhere useful?

Comment: @skube Right. In this case it's not clear to me why the user wants to discard both stdout and stderr. OP probably just wanted to understand what the syntax meant.

Answer (score 5):

`2` refers to STDERR. `2>&1` will send STDERR to the same location as `1` (STDOUT).

Answer (score 0):

My understand as follow:

If you only want to read the Output and Error information of the command on the screen, then just write:
`curl http://www.google.com`

And some times you want to save the Output information to a file instead of terminal screen for later review, then you can write:
`curl http://www.google.com > logfile`

But in this way, the StdErr information will be omitted, since `>` only redirect the StdOut to `logfile`.

So if you care about the error information of the command once it fail to execute, then you need to combine StdOut with StdErr by using `2>&1` (which means fold StdErr into StdOut), so the following command line can be written:
`curl http://www.google.com > logfile` 2>&1