# Started an application through SSH, command line now gone, what happens next?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, putty

**Context:** This is a very basic question

Using Putty and SSH for the first time to do some serious server setup and run into the situation where I have started a process that I do not want to stop.

The process is the [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) WSGI HTTP Server (running on Centos 6.3).

The command I used to start the process is (as per their [Quick Start](http://gunicorn.org/)):

```
gunicorn -w 4 myapp:app
```

At this point in the work session, I have lost the command prompt. This must be such a non-issue that it doesn't even enter into an experienced user's consciousness. But unfortunately at my level of experience, I am left with several fundamental questions:

- Does the fact that I have lost the command prompt mean that the process is still running?
- How do I get back to the command prompt without killing the process?
- How do I come back and monitor the process later?
- How do I eventually kill the process?

Any help is appreciated, thanks so much!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
nohup gunicorn -w 4 myapp:app &> /dev/null &
```

This will

- execute `gunicorn -w 4`
- send the process to background - that's the `&` at the end. You can view background jobs via `jobs` and bring them to foreground via `fg $id` if they e.g. wait for interaction
- mute the process by redirecting standard error and standard output to `/dev/null`, so it won't show in your shell `&> /dev/null`
- make sure that the process will not be killed if the parent (here your shell) ends. `nohup`

---

**EDIT:**

To monitor the program as whole it would be fine to monitor output of the program.

So we can modify the command in this manner:

- duplicate standard error output to standard output stream `2>&1`. More on this construction can be found here: [What does “2>&1” do in command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/71428/what-does-21-do-in-command-line)
- redirect standard output stream to our file `>~/gunicorn.log`

The final command will look like this:

```
nohup gunicorn -w 4 myapp:app 2>&1 >~/gunicorn.log &
```

---

To kill the process you could fire series of these commands:

```
ps aux | grep gunicorn
```

then identify the PID (I would refer to it as `$PID`) of the gunicorn process and stop it gracefully:

```
kill $PID
```

or stop it forcefully:

```
kill -9 $PID
```

---

You could customize it to your further needs.

Answer (score 4):

> Does the fact that I have lost the command prompt mean that the process is still running?

Unlikely. The process will have a connection to the virtual terminal of ssh, which will eventually time out and kill all the processes associated with that terminal - though gunicorn could be written in a manner that it doesn't exit when the controlling terminal disappears.

> How do I get back to the command prompt without killing the process?

If the terminal is still alive, hit CTRL+Z to get back to the command prompt, then write `bg` to place gnuicorn in the background (and use `fg` to get back to the process so you can kill it - e.g. with `CTRL+C`).

Starting it as either `gunicorn -w 4 myapp:app &` will place the process in the background of the shell immediately - though depending on the server it might still get killed when your ssh session ends. Running `nohup gunicorn -w 4 myapp:app &` will ensure the process to run even when you disconnect. Read the man page of `nohup`

Another option is to run the process in a terminal that allows you to reattach to it. That's what the GNU screen or the tmux allows you to do - effectivly allowing you to disconnect the ssh session, connect back later on and reattach to an existing terminal session.

> How do I come back and monitor the process later?

You can't, unless you run the process inside a GNU screen or tmux session - in which case the docs/tutorials for screen or tmux will tell you the detail - or you've started the server to run as a service/in the background.

> How do I eventually kill the process?

Most server programs will have a managment interface (e.g. commands you'll have to run), and you'll have to find the relevant information in the documentation.

Or they integrate themselves in the linux/unix startup and service management procedures, in which case you manage them as any other services , e.g. `/sbin/service fooserver start` `/sbin/service fooserver stop` on some linux distros.

Or you have to do it manually. Find the process by running `ps -ef |grep fooserver` to find its pid, and kill it, `kill <the pid>`. Or look in the documentation if the erver can write a "pid file" when it starts up, so you can find the process id in that file later on.

Now, it seems at least gunicorn has a -D argument, which is used to place the server in the background, disconnecting it from  the terminal, so it doesn't get killed when your ssh/putty connection disconnects. See http://gunicorn.org/configure.html#server-mechanics

You'll then have to manage/monitor it manually, i.e. kill it as I mentioned above, monitor it through the log file it produces - or any integrated monitoring webapp or commands gnuicorn might have.

The intent here is clearly for someone to package gnuicorn for a particular linux/*nix variant, and write the relevant scripts and config files to integrate it into the native service management of the distro. (e.g. a standard script under /etc/init.d/ to start and stop the server, used on many 
linux'es)

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes, the process is running.

2) You can start the process in the background by starting it as

```
gunicorn -w 4 myapp:app &
```

3) You can find the process ID (pid) with

```
ps aux | grep gunicorn
```

4) To kill the process, you can kill it with

```
kill (the pid you found in 3)
```

To force the process to stop, run

```
kill -9 (the pid you found in 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [`nohup(1)`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/1/nohup/) command for starting background processes and being able to disconnect your terminal session.

Answer (score 1):

Going forward, you may find the [gnu screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) are quite helpful while working on a terminal like putty.Or even the better alternative for *gnu screen* -- [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), which gets more and more popular now due to its powerful, consistent, well-documented command interfaces.