# shell standard streams redirection order OR 2>&1 1>/dev/null vs 1>/dev/null 2>&1

Tags: bash, redirection, stdout, stderr, stdin

Can somebody please clarify differences? Is some of those considered as best practice? If I remember correct I somehow on SO read that this `1>/dev/null` should precede this: `2>&1`

```
ls -al /doesNotExists 2>&1 1>/dev/null
ls -al /doesNotExists 1>/dev/null 2>&1

ls -al /doesNotExists 1>&2 2>/dev/null
ls -al /doesNotExists 2>/dev/null 1>&2

ls -la /doesNotExists 2<&1 1>/dev/null
ls -la /doesNotExists 2<&1 2>/dev/null

ls -la /doesNotExists 1<&2 1>/dev/null
ls -la /doesNotExists 1<&2 2>/dev/null

ls -la /doesNotExists 1>/dev/null 2<&1
ls -la /doesNotExists 2>/dev/null 2<&1

ls -la /doesNotExists 1>/dev/null 1<&2
ls -la /doesNotExists 2>/dev/null 1<&2
```

Comment: Read `n>&m` as, **redirect stream `n` to where `m` is currently directed to**. Not redirect stream `n` to stream `m`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "2>&1" do in command line?](http://superuser.com/questions/71428/what-does-21-do-in-command-line)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### shell standard streams redirection order

The order matters as the outcome is different. Take your first example:

```
ls -al /doesNotExists 2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

This directs only standard output to nul, because the standard error was duplicated to standard output *before* standard output was redirected to dirlist.

```
ls -al /doesNotExists 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

This directs both standard output and standard error to nul.

---

#### Bash Reference Manual: Redirections

> Note that the order of redirections is significant. For example, the
>   command
>
> ```
> ls > dirlist 2>&1
> ```
>
> directs both standard output (file descriptor 1) and standard error
>   (file descriptor 2) to the file dirlist, while the command
>
> ```
> ls 2>&1 > dirlist
> ```
>
> directs only the standard output to file dirlist, because the standard
>   error was made a copy of the standard output before the standard
>   output was redirected to dirlist.

Source [Bash Reference Manual: Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)

---

#### Tutorial

There is a nice illustrated tutorial at [Illustrated Redirection Tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial) which makes this easier to understand:

> **Order Of Redirection, i.e., "> file 2>&1" vs. "2>&1 >file"**
>
> While it doesn't matter where the redirections appears on the command
>   line, their order does matter. They are setup from left to right.
>
> ```
> 2>&1 >file
> ```
>
> A common error, is to do command 2>&1 > file to redirect both stderr
>   and stdout to file. Let's see what's going on. First we type the
>   command in our typical terminal, the descriptors look like this:
>
> ```
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> standard input   ( 0 ) ---->| /dev/pts/5            |
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
>
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> standard output  ( 1 ) ---->| /dev/pts/5            |
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
>
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> standard error   ( 2 ) ---->| /dev/pts/5            |
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> ```
>
> Then our shell, Bash sees 2>&1 so it duplicates 1, and the file
>   descriptor look like this:
>
> ```
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> standard input   ( 0 ) ---->| /dev/pts/5            |
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
>
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> standard output  ( 1 ) ---->| /dev/pts/5            |
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
>
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> standard error   ( 2 ) ---->| /dev/pts/5            |
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> ```
>
> That's right, nothing has changed, 2 was already pointing to the same
>   place as 1. Now Bash sees > file and thus changes stdout:
>
> ```
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> standard input   ( 0 ) ---->| /dev/pts/5            |
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
>
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> standard output  ( 1 ) ---->| file                  |
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
>
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> standard error   ( 2 ) ---->| /dev/pts/5            |
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> ```
>
> And that's not what we want.
>
> ```
> >file 2>&1
> ```
>
> Now let's look at the correct command >file 2>&1. We start as in the
>   previous example, and Bash sees > file:
>
> ```
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> standard input   ( 0 ) ---->| /dev/pts/5            |
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
>
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> standard output  ( 1 ) ---->| file                  |
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
>
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> standard error   ( 2 ) ---->| /dev/pts/5            |
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> ```
>
> Then it sees our duplication 2>&1:
>
> ```
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> standard input   ( 0 ) ---->| /dev/pts/5            |
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
>
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> standard output  ( 1 ) ---->| file                  |
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
>
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> standard error   ( 2 ) ---->| file                  |
>                   ---       +-----------------------+
> ```
>
> And voila, both 1 and 2 are redirected to file.

Comment: Thank you, nice info graphic. Just two clarifications: 1. `ls > /dev/null` is it the same as `ls 1> /dev/null` 2. When are `<` used? I have tried  `ls -l >file &1<2` and it is not the same as `ls >file 2>&1`. Is `cat file` equivalent to `cat <file` are there any examples where it is not equivalent? thank you

Comment: @WakanTanka  1/ yes (1 just means std output). 2/ < is used to redirect _input_ (cat file is the same as cat < file)

Comment: When it is useful to redirect input, it can open it as I've shown, why redirect?

Comment: Just to clarify the answer in the comment: `cat <file` is the same as `cat file` because cat reads from stdin when it gets no arguments. `ls file` is not the same as `ls <file`, as the later expects to find a list of files inside file, and the former just list one single file, `file`.

Comment: This explanation is very nice. Thanks for the diagram.