# Modify 2>&1 so that output goes to a specific file and any errors or other output goes to a log file I can monitor?

Tags: command-line, shell, redirection, tail

[I'm reading this post](https://superuser.com/questions/71428/what-does-21-do-in-command-line) and I don't fully follow the answer.

I wondered if I could modify this, what's it called, command redirect?

What I would like:

1. Don't hang, use ampersand `&` to move on to the next command
2. Output the data generated by the command to file `data.json`
3. Any problems, error messages or issues running the command, output them to bqlog.txt

Is this possible?

E.g. I currently have this command:

```
bq query --max_rows=1000000 --use_legacy_sql=false --format=json --batch=true --headless=true 'select * from `ga4-extract.analytics_123456789.events_'"$RUNDATE"'`;' > data.json
```

It's failing after about 30 minutes and I cannot see the output or what the issue is. This is on a github actions runner and the console output of the workflow just gives a failed status but, unique to this workflow, no console output indicating the error.

I wanted to modify my command so that I can output to data.json like I already have, but then also move on to the next step of monitoring the bqlog.txt file with `tail -F bqlog.txt`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

The `2>&1` means the following:

```
2 : stderr
> : output redirect
& : copy file descriptor
1 : file descriptor 1
```

So: stderr output redirect to wherever file descriptor 1 (stdout) is directed. Default: the screen.

This means, stderr is outputted to the screen.

Your question is, how can I redirect the output of my command to file 1, and the stderr to another?

Your command becomes:

```
command >output1.txt 2>output2.txt
```

To use your own code, you would write (I've added enters to avoid a scrollbar and making it readable. The same command without the enters and scrollbar is below:

```
bq query --max_rows=1000000 --use_legacy_sql=false --format=json 
   --batch=true --headless=true 
   'select * from `ga4-extract.analytics_123456789.events_'"$RUNDATE"'`;
   ' >data.json 2>bglog.txt
```

or without enters:

```
bq query --max_rows=1000000 --use_legacy_sql=false --format=json --batch=true --headless=true 'select * from `ga4-extract.analytics_123456789.events_'"$RUNDATE"'`;' >data.json 2>bglog.txt
```

Do note, this command will create an empty file if there is no output, and it will overwrite the file on every command. If you want to append, use >> instead. Eg:

```
>>data.json 2>>bglog.txt
```

In addition you may want to add the following:

```
echo --------------------- >> data.json
echo --------------------- >> bglog.txt
```

This will write ---- to both files, helping you to see when an old execution and new exection takes place.

Comment: Ah thank you! I can output err direct to console then? Don't even need to follow the log file? Is that right?

Comment: by default stderr is logged to console, you don't need to do anything for that. the `>txt` only logs normal output. By using `2>&1` you say, I want stderr to be redirected to whatever my output already is. so `>txt 2>&1` basically makes stderr also output to txt

Comment: `&` does not mean ‘append to’, that would be `>>`.

Comment: Regarding multi-line - you can use `^` to break long lines in bat/cmd scripts.

Comment: "append" has a particular meaning when outputting to a file: it means _all_ writes go the very end of the (existing) file, regardless of anything else. You can create a redirection in append mode with `>>`, it's also different from a regular one (`>`), also in that the regular mode truncates the file first. `&` only tells to copy an existing file descriptor, it does _not_ change between regular and append mode. (the answer also uses the proper meaning of the word later)